# How to add active class in wordpress to anchor tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog') ?>"
  <?php if(get_post_type()=='post') echo 'class="active"'?>>Blog</a>
</li>
```

I am trying to add active class to different links in navigation but this code gives an error. Can somebody correct the mistake in above-mentioned code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about another way?

```
function add_class_to_href( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( in_array('current_page_item', $item->classes) ) {
        $classes['class'] = 'active';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_href', 10, 2 );
```

Perhaps this is the way to go, if I understand correctly. Anyways, hope this helps!

I know it's a whole function, but this should work. Paste this into `function.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

*Include the following jquery code to your footer and your page will work fine*

$(".current_page_item a").addClass("active");

Hope this will help you

Comment: Copycat end of answer